# XNA 4 2D Tiled Sprite - Weird Line

Tags: c#, .net, xna, xna-4.0

I have a 512x512 image that I need to tile for a background.

I am doing this by setting `SamplerState.LinearWrap` and setting a larger source rectangle on the image.

```
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.NonPremultiplied, SamplerState.LinearWrap, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone);
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, bounds, bounds, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

`bounds` is `new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768)`

Right now it is looking like this:

[image: Game Background]

Those lines are where the image is being tiled.  The original png does not have any lines on the edges (I zoomed in and checked it out in Photoshop).

What is going on here to cause this?  [Here is an example project on DropBox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3702398/TestXnaTile.zip).

I tried using a non-power-of-two texture, and it gave an error on the `SamplerState`, so I am using a texture of proper size, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a graphical artifact in the image.

I copied and pasted a section of the image to the edges and it works as expected, your code is working.  Try it with a different image to confirm.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have our designer look at it and let you know.

Comment: Looks like you are right, there is some partially transparent pixels on the top and left edges of the image.